# Enter array size for a string array and int array via keyboard

Tags: c++

How can I enter the size of an array using the keyboard for an integer array and a string array? The value I enter will be applied to both arrays.  I will be using two for loops to populate both arrays with strings and integers. Everything I tried up to now has failed.  Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Just use `cin >> n`.

Comment: ... and please show some code, even if  you did  not get  it to work...

Comment: @StephanLechner That's incorrect. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) requires a compile time constant as a _template parameter_ so passing a variable that is not determined at compile time (Such as user-input) would not work. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is an option, however. (`int n; std::cin >> n; std::vector(n)`)

Comment: Typo above: `std::vector<int> vec(n)`

Comment: Because array's require compile time constant for length.  I  recommend you use std::string and std::vector<int>.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that for dynamic arrays:

```
unsigned int size;
std::cout << "size: ";
std::cin >> size;

int* pInt = new int[size];
std::string* pstr = new std::string[size]; 

// Use loops to read / write
```

Finally you should free up memory:

```
delete[] pInt;
delete[] pstr;
```

- Remember that arrays are fixed-size at compile time containers. Some compilers allow `VLA`.
- The thing I recommend is to use `std::vector`:

  ```
  std::vector<int> vi;
  vstd::vecotr<std::string> vstr;
  unsigned int size;

  std::cout << "size: ";
  std::cin >> size;

  vi.resize(size);
  vstr.resize(size);

  std::string str;
  int x;

  for(auto i(0); i != size; ++i){
      std::getline(std::cin, str);
      vstr.push_back(str);

      std::cin >> x;
      vi.push_back(x);
  }
  ```

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a better option than raw dynamic arrays which have to be manually deleted and are troublesome to use as pointers.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: Edited now.